# Git Tortoise issue

Tags: git

I have 2 members in GIT on my machine that are 'not versioned ' status is 'unknown'. not sure what to do with them./ One of them i can see is not an issue (the code) the other i cannot locate it's something like common/common debug log text not really that critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to track your source code and the rest, like log files or compiled artifacts, you want to ignore. Set up your .gitignore file correctly and you should not see irrelevant files showing up in `git status`.